# Simple Youtube Search PHP Script

Tags: php, youtube

Does anybody know any good simple youtube search scripts in php that I could use right off the bat? I don't want to use the Zend Framework (not installed), just the basic REST calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what's wrong with the [official youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)?

you don't need the whole ZF for that, it should work separatley too.

Comment: I think there is one wrong thing with YT api, came across this having small "issue" with API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834296/google-api-youtube-v3-quota-runs-in-no-time

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/

ok

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube/
Go there view the source code, there's tons out there, perhaps use google and type in PHP YouTube and sit back and check them all out...but be prepared YouTube loves to change things so you'll be back ;)