# Google API Youtube V3 - Quota runs in no time

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building app that uses Google Youtube Data API V3
Everything is fine, except before I'm able to test app I run out of quota.

So hence my question is if I'm doing something wrong? Seems like daily quota does not allow me to query more than 100 search queries.

Which seems odd, cause even if trying to develop any kind of web app that uses API, I run out of quota and can't do anything in no time.

From what I found over quota calculators, a *search* is *worth* 100 points or so.

If I were to finish my App, then trying to release it to people would mean it will stop working after first few searches.
So is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How can we tell without seeing your code?

Comment: @johnh10 don't think code is needed here. I used default examples from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
I only was changing `q` parameter